# Why is Green always associated with Islam?

Tags: symbolism

It seems like most Muslim countries have green in their flags (indeed, Qaddahfi's Libyan flag was just green!).  This color seems to be associated with politically with most Islamic states, but I'm wondering why.  Is there a source to the tradition? Is it in the texts? Or, is it just a coincidence?

Comment: "Qaddahfi's Libyan flag was just green" That's not a proper example indeed!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Wikipedia has an article on this specifically.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_in_Islam)

> "Reclining on green Cushions and rich Carpets of beauty" (sura 55, verse 76)
>
> "Upon them will be green garments of fine silk and heavy brocade, and they will be adorned with bracelets of silver; and their Lord will give to them to drink of a Water Pure and Holy." (sura 76, verse 21)

It's the color of a lot of things in Paradise. The Quran doesn't really mention a lot of other colors positively, IIRC. So if someone wanted to pick out an "Islamic" color, it would just have to be green.

Comment: I also want to add that, The prophet (SM)'s favorite color was green. I'll update this with a citation later

Comment: Salaam and welcome to Islam.SE . Please take a look at the FAQ and highly upvoted questions and answers to get a sense of what we do here. This is a focused question and answer website and unlike a lot of other forums and Islamic website you may have prior experience with. We encourage answers here to answer the question in a self-contained and well-referenced manner and to be substantially more than just a link.  Also we discourage speculation and opinion. Please feel free to join us in the chat room and ask any questions you might have.

Answer (score 1):

There is no relation between green and Islam. I think it just a coincidence. If you take a look at [all countries' flags](https://www.cia.gov/library/publications/the-world-factbook/docs/flagsoftheworld.html) you will find that green is very common in many flags.

Qaddahfi's flag was green because he wrote a book called the green book, every thing in Libya (before revolution) was named green. [See Libyan flag history](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_of_Libya#Great_Socialist_People.27s_Libyan_Arab_Jamahiriya_.281977.E2.80.932011.29).

Also Saudi-Arabia flag is green, but I don't know why!

The old Islamic flag (at prophet Mohamed's time) was black with white writing. The color of Islamic empires after it differs in colors. Sometime black, sometimes red and sometimes green.