# Madinah prophet grave dome earlier colors?

Tags: masjid

I read somewhere that the dome was made of wood and not painted, then it was changed to yellow for some years or centuries and then it was painted blue and it was changed again to green.

Searching Google isn't giving color names.

My question is which colors the dome over the Prophets grave has seen?

Comment: What influence has this knowledge on your iman? The mosque has been re-built several times similar to the al-Masjid al-Haram.

Comment: My relatives keep photographs of madinah at home, and revere green color because of dome, I want to inform them the color has no specific blessing. In indian sub continent the green dome has huge zealotism.

Comment: Then simply check the site [Why is green always associated with islam?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/1764/why-is-green-always-associated-with-islam) and [The symbolic meaning of the colour green in Islam](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/43833/the-symbolic-meaning-of-the-colour-green-in-islam)

Comment: White is also preferred color as per logic of above